# into vs. partition

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

This makes sense:

```
user=> (into {} [[:a 1] [:b 2]])
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

But why does this generate an error?

```
user=> (into {} (partition 2 [:a 1 :b 2]))

ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry  clojure.lang.ATransientMap.conj (ATransientMap.java:44)
```

Just to be sure:

```
user=> (partition 2 [:a 1 :b 2])
((:a 1) (:b 2))
```

Does `into` have a problem with lazy sequences? If so, why?

Beyond an explanation of why this doesn't work, what is the recommended way to conj a sequence of key-value pairs like `[:a 1 :b 2]` into a map? (`apply conj` doesn't seem to work, either.)

Answer (score 4):

You can `apply` the sequence to `assoc`:

```
(apply assoc {:foo 1} [:a 1 :b 2])
=> {:foo 1, :a 1, :b 2}
```

> Does into have a problem with lazy sequences? If so, why?

No, `into` is commonly used with lazily evaluated sequences. This is lazy, but each key/value tuple is a vector, which is why it works when `into` is reducing the pairs into the map:

```
(into {} (map vector (range 3) (repeat :x)))
=> {0 :x, 1 :x, 2 :x}
```

This doesn't work because the key/value pairs are lists:

```
(into {} (map list (range 3) (repeat :x)))
```

So the difference isn't laziness; it's due to `into` using `reduce` using `conj` on the map, which only works with *vector* key/value pairs (or `MapEntry`s):

```
(conj {} [:a 1]) ;; ok
(conj {} (MapEntry. :a 1)) ;; ok
(conj {} '(:a 1)) ;; not ok
```

Update: `assoc` wrapper for applying empty/nil sequences as suggested in comments:

```
(defn assoc*
  ([m] m)
  ([m k v & kvs]
   (apply assoc m k v kvs)))
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I'd love to see an explanation of why `into` fails and `assoc` works. Usually Clojure behaves as expected; I'd like to find out what I need to know to "expect" this.

Comment: I just found that `(apply assoc {} sequence)` fails if `sequence` is empty.

Comment: You can use the transducer version in the other answer in that case: `(into {} (map vec) (partition 2 []))`

Comment: Or if you find yourself doing this a lot, you could introduce a helper wrapping `assoc` with an extra unary overload that returns the map. If it's just one or two places, an `if` might be the most straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way – *(assuming the seq arg is non-empty, as pointed out by the OP)* – would be

```
Clojure 1.9.0
user=> (apply assoc {} [:a 1 :b 2])
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

The version with `partition` doesn't work because the blocks that `partition` returns are seqs and those are not treated as map entries when `conj`'d on to a map the way vectors and actual map entries are.

E.g. `(into {} (map vec) (partition 2 [:a 1 :b 2]))` would work because here the pairs get converted to vectors before `conj`ing.

Still the approach with `assoc` is preferable unless there's some particular circumstance that makes `into` convenient (like, say, if you have a bunch of transducers that you want to use for preprocessing your `partition`-generated pairs etc.).

Comment: Can you explain why `conj` treats 2-element vectors are treated as map entries but not 2-element seqs? It seems to violate the principle of least astonishment. Also, why is `apply assoc` preferable to `into` with `(map vec)`?

Answer (score 1):

Clojure treats a 2-vec such as `[:a 1]` as equivalent to a `MapEntry`, doing what amounts to "automatic type conversion". I try to avoid this and always be explicit.

```
(first {:a 1})        => <#clojure.lang.MapEntry [:a 1]>
(conj {:a 1} [:b 2])  => <#clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap {:a 1, :b 2}>
```

So we see that a MapEntry prints like a vector but has a different type (just like a Clojure `seq` prints like a `list` but has a different type).  `seq` converts a Clojure map into a sequence of MapEntry's, and `first` gets us the first one (most Clojure functions call `(seq ...)` on any input collections before any other processing).

Notice that `conj` does the inverse type conversion, treating the ***vector*** `[:b 2]` as if it were a MapEntry.  However, `conj` won't perform automatic type conversion for a `list` or a `seq`:

```
(throws? (conj {:a 1} '(:b 2)))
(throws? (into {:a 1} '(:b 2)))
```

`into` has the same problem [since it is basically just](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6763) `(reduce conj <1st-arg> <2nd-seq>)`.

The other answers already have 3 ways that work:

```
(assoc {}   :b 2)             => {:b 2}
(conj  {}  [:b 2])            => {:b 2}
(into  {} [[:a 1] [:b 2]])    => {:a 1, :b 2}
```

However, I would avoid those and stick to either `hash-map` or `sorted-map`, both of which avoid the problem of empty input seqs:

```
(apply hash-map [])           => {}            ; works for empty input seq
(apply hash-map [:a 1 :b 2])  => {:b 2, :a 1}
```

If your input sequence is a list of pairs, `flatten` is sometimes helpful:

```
(apply sorted-map (flatten  [[:a 1] [:b 2]])) => {:a 1, :b 2}
(apply   hash-map (flatten '((:a 1) (:b 2)))) => {:a 1, :b 2}
```

---

## P.S.

Please be note that these are not the same:

- java.util.Map$Entry (listed in jdk docs as "Map.Entry")
- clojure.lang.MapEntry

## P.P.S

If you already have a map and want to merge in a (possibly empty) sequence of key-value pairs, just use a combination of `into` and `hash-map`:

```
(into {:a 1} (apply hash-map []))       => {:a 1}
(into {:a 1} (apply hash-map [:b 2]))   => {:a 1, :b 2}
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up hash-map—and explaining what's going on! Any suggestions for when the map isn't empty? (In my actual code, I'm trying to add to a map that might already have key-value pairs in it.)